# Converter std::vector p/ std::array implicitamente?

Tags: c++

Como faço p/ estender o `std::vector` de forma que exista uma conversão implícita de `std::array` para `std::vector`?

Imagina que tenho o seguinte:

```
template <class T, int N>
std::array<T, N> vector_to_array (std::vector<T> x) {
  std::array<T,N> y;
  std::copy_n(x.begin(), N, y.begin());
  return y;
}

std::array<int,2> times2 (std::array<int, 2> x) {
  x[0] = x[0]*2;
  x[1] = x[1]*2;
  return x;
}

void times2vector (std::vector<int>  x) {
  auto res = times2(vector_to_array<int, 2>(x));
  std::cout << res[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << res[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Eu queria evitar a chamada explícita de `vector_to_array<int, 2>(x)` e fazer com que isso acontecesse implicitamente.

Comment: Você pode herdar em outra classe e criar um operador de *cast*, mas eu acho que não compensa, todo mundo anda correndo de fazer *casts* implícitos, precisa ser caso bem pensado, em geral só estar no tipo desde o começo e não fazendo herança, dá mais problemas que solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso, a melhor solução me parece simplesmente fazer uma *function overloading*.Confira-se:

```
std::array<int,2> times2(std::array<int, 2> x) {
  x[0] = x[0]*2;
  x[1] = x[1]*2;
  return x;
}

std::array<int,2> times2 (std::vector<int> x){
   return times2(vector_to_array<int, 2>(x));
}

void times2vector (std::vector<int>  x) {
  auto res = times2(x);
  std::cout << res[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << res[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Contudo, não foi isso que você pediu e eu desconfio que você tenha em algum momento trabalhado com essa possibilidade. Porém, a solução do jeito que você quer esbarra dois graves problemas, o primeiro desses problemas decorre da imprevisibilidade ao se estender (ou herdar) o `std::vector`

Eu particularmente desconheço se existam regras claras sobre a herança da maioria das classes da *standard library* ou se não está definido e é, portanto, algo que depende da implementação. Quanto a isso, desnecessário dizer que se a implementação usar, por exemplo, um private member *tout est perdu*. Friend classes e functions também são problemáticas e eu creio que existam outros casos. Um exemplo:

```
class myvector: public std::vector<int>{};

int main(){
   //essa parte funciona
   myvector a0;
   std::vector<int> a1;
   a0.push_back(42);
   a1.push_back(21);

   std::cout << "myvector: " << a0[0] << "\t std::vector: " << a1[0] << '\n';

   //mas aqui a vaca vai para o brejo
   std::vector<int> b0{2, 4, 5};
   myvector b1{2, 4, 5}; //no matching function for call to ...

   return 0;
}
```

O segundo problema está relacionado à conversão implícita. Na maioria dos casos, é perfeitamente possível usar o **implicit conversion operator** para criar uma conversão implícita definida pelo usuário. Confira-se o exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
   int i = 11;
   int j = 13;
};

class B{
public:
   char i = 'S';
   //cria uma conversão implicita de A para B
   operator A() const {return A{42, 45};}
};

//note que a função somente recebe A como parâmetro
void print_number(A a){
   std::cout << a.i << '\n';
}

int main(){
   A a;
   B b;
   print_number(a);
   print_number(b);// mas com o "operator A()", agora a função aceita B numa boa
   return 0;
}

/*output:
>> 11
>> 42
*/
```

No entanto, no caso do `std::array`, isso é extremamente problemático porque ele não só é um template como é um template em que um dos parâmetros não é sequer um tipo e isso simplesmente não combina bem com **operators**. Por exemplo, isso aqui definitivamente não vai funcionar:

```
template <class T, int N>
std::array<T, N> vector_to_array (std::vector<T> x) {
  std::array<T,N> y;
  std::copy_n(x.begin(), N, y.begin());
  return y;
}

class mvector : public std::vector<int> {
   operator std::array<T, int N>() const { //ops... template argument 2 is invalid
      return vector_to_array<T, N>(*this);
   }
};
```

Por fim, alguns sites consultados para posterior leitura e *workarounds* (infelizmente, todos em inglês, assim como *workarounds* que significa 'soluções alternativas' ):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762049/templated-operator-overload-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector